# How do I set an Intent extra persistent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Activity, that has been started with an Intent, containing some intent extra data. After reading this data, I want to put other data in the extra bundle and I want also to ensure that it will be saved persistent (i.e. for the next time my activity is recreated).

Right now I do something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
       super.onCreate(b);
       if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("ANIMATION_RAN", false)){
           runAnimation();
       }
    }

    private boolean runAnimation(){
        ...
        getIntent.putExtra("ANIMATION_RAN", true);
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to add extras persistently. As far as I know there was a special method or a main difference between `intent.putExtra()` and `intent.getExtras().put()` but I can't remember which was the correct one nor I couldn't find more details from the documentation.

I just want to store that an certain animation has been ran and should never run for a second time again (even not on activity recreation)

Update:
I just want to store a boolean flag that an animation has been ran. I don't want to run the animation a second time again (even not on activity recreation). So no, I can't store that as shared preferences, database or file because  otherwise that flag would be used for instances of `MyActivity` and that's not what I want. I can't use `onSaveInstanceState()` because I have to ensure that the animation does not run on recreation.

Comment: But why can't you use `onSaveInstanceState()`? The result will be passed to `onCreate` like you would like.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "activity recreation" here. If your process is killed by Android due to idleness or resource reclamation, when the user returns to your app, Android will recreate the activity and provide the `Bundle` returned from `onSaveInstanceState()` as a parameter to `onCreate()`. Please explain why you think this won't work.

Comment: in that case bundle will be null

Answer (score 0):

You can save a bundle when the activity is killed by the system and re-create.
Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState

But if you would like to store it when the user kill and start again your application, you have to use something like [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) or [files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

SharedPreference is what you looking for I think!

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I'm looking for. I'm pretty sure that is a way to save it in the intent persistently

Answer (score 0):

Kevinrob is correct. I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish. You want to store a bunch of data in an intent and keep it running, correct?

The issue with that is that it will bog down the device. Storing data for later should be done with the shared preferences, not with another process.

If you are looking for convenience in storing your data, look at GSON, a json library for java made by google. You can give it an instance of a class containing all of your data, and it will convert it into a json string that you can store in the SharedPreferences. The string can be given back to Gson and it will spit your object back out with all your variables retaining their values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: After reading your question again, I'm not so sure this is relevant.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I don't want to store a buch of data.

Comment: Can you explain further what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to store a boolean flag that an animation has been ran. I don't want to run the animation a second time again (even not on activity recreation). So no, I can't store that as shared prefernces, database or file because  otherwise that flag would be used for instances of `MyActivity` and that's not what I want. I can't use `onSaveInstanceState()` because I have to ensure that the animation does not run on recreation. I know that this can be done with an intent, I'm just not sure if the `putExtra()` is the correct one to store it persistently for recreation of activities.

Comment: I believe you are over complicating things. If you are simply keeping track of a boolean, why not keep it static in another class and check if the animation has been run before you run the animation?

Comment: Because of Activity recreation! It's hard to explain, but if the activity is destroyed in the background (i.e. Android needs memory) then the Activity class and all static methods will probably be instantiated for the first time again after recreation (i.e. user reopens the app) and the static fields having the default value.

Comment: If the activity is destroyed in the background, it will still run the onDestroy method. You can still add the proper checks to make saving the boolean in the shared preferences an option.

Comment: Sorry, but the intent is volatile. It represent an action. `Bundle` in an `Intent` won't appear by miracle again.  
You can store it for later somewhere, or store it for re-creating (like screen rotation, low memory, etc...).

Comment: Have you tried adding flags to the intent? Such as FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION... this is the closest thing I could find that would be of help here. My apologize. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags(int)